# how to read a json result using variable in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs package that I can read in console with

```
myapps.app({appId: '123'}).then(console.log); //return json result in console
```

I need to read it using a variable result:

```
var result = myapps.app({appId: '123'});
console.log(result);
```

but it's not working!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you say "it's not working" it is helpful to let us know what you expect to happen, what happened instead, and if any error messages showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Because `myapps.app` is asynchronous function which returns a promise, to use it in a synchronous style code, you must use the `async/await` syntax, like this

```
var result = await myapps.app({appId: '123'})
console.log(result)
```

But make sure this code is wrapped with an `async` function.

```
async function() { ... }
```

Or immediately invoked async function like this

```
(async function() { ... })()
```

Here's a resource could help you with `async/await` https://javascript.info/async-await